# Chat program non local

Tags: c#, server, client, chat

i found this code:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-client.htm

It works fine local.

I then went to https://www.whatismyip.com/ to get my ip.

I typed in my ip here instead of "127.0.0.1" in the Client.exe:

```
clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

Not working.

I want to send the Client.Exe to my friend and have him connect to the server running on my computer.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's quite normal that you cannot connect to your external IP from within your network. Possibly your friend _can_ connect using your IP. That all depends on how you have set up your server and your network.

Comment: ok, i send the client.exe to my friend, but he gets a time out....

Comment: What can i try now.....The error message on his screen is something about a path leading to my pc???

Comment: Should i send the Soulution to him and make him compile it on his PC?

Comment: Or you can compile it but put the IP address in an app.config...

Comment: ok, I send the solution to my friend, but he could't compile it....namespaces already exists....

Comment: I have looked at "What is App.config in C#.NET? How to use it?
", but i have no idea of what to do... I just started with C#, so i probably need smaller steps..... Thanks anyway.....

Comment: You'll need to open your firewall to expose your server to the internet if you want your friend to be able to connect externally, look into *port forwarding*

Comment: ok. thanks, i'll give it a try.....

Comment: When i log in on to my router, i see a list off ports i can activate...I have activated a service called FTP-DATA with TCP protokol...there is no Extern HOST IP, only Intern wich starts with 192.168.... Should i now be able to use the Intern IP and Port provided, in my Client.exe?

Comment: The firewall is open(LantoWan and WantoLan)....i followed this tutorial to make a static ip https://portforward.com/networking/static-xp.htm, but i lost connection to the net, and had to put it back to original....? I could show an image of my router settings if that would be any help? I Have some options there to create my own rules, and Port Triggering options... but i'm not sure what to write in all those fields.

Comment: You have two options: compile the program with your IP in it and let your friend run it. It _might_ work. If that doesn't work, you will need to learn troubleshoot your network, and if you want to reach your external IP from within, you may need to set up something like a [hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat). That is a bigger challenge in networking than writing your first C# program.

Comment: Alternatively, you may try to write a chat client for a chat server that is hosted somewhere else. That you could write and debug yourself and give as-is to your friend.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give another try.....